# Python cant find module

Tags: python, python-import

My file structure:

```
-launch.py
---folder
-----folder
-------__init__py
-------test.py
-------test1.py
```

launch.py

```
os.system('python3.6 -m folder.folder.test')
```

test.py

```
import test1
```

test1.py

```
def test_print():
    print("Testing testing 123")
```

I'm getting a module not found error because, for some reason, python is looking for modules in the directory `launch.py` resides in. I am able to successfully import this in test.py using `import folder.folder.test1` I would just use that, but the program I am modifying already has way too many imports using `import test1` (since it seems to work fine in Windows).
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import test1` looks for a *top-level module*. You can't import a module inside the same package without telling Python explicitly to look at that package.

Use

```
from . import test1
```

or

```
from folder.folder import test1
```

`import test1` only works if the directory `folder/folder/` is present on the Python module search path. Any code that is relying on `import test1` to work will only do so if started directly with `.../folder/folder` as the current working directory, or when you have added that directory to `sys.path` explicitly (either by updating that list from Python code, or by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable).

For example, from the `folder.folder.test` module, you could use:

```
import sys, os
HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, HERE)
```

before using `import test1`. *I recommend against doing this*; fix the project instead to work correctly with the packaged namespace.

Comment: Thank you! So from what I've researched, simply writing `import test1` works in python2.7, correct?

Comment: Yes, because in Python 2 the module search starts in the current package before searching further. Use `from __future__ import absolute_import` to switch Python 2 code to the Python 3 model.